# Sort and Save Matrices Eigenvectors to a Larger Matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, code-review

We are going to sort and save all orthoginalized-eigenvectors of  4*4 random matrices (produced in any iteration) to a larger matrix such as storagematrix.

Since, produced random matrices are 4*4, and between 0 and 2, there are 11 numbers with 0.2 intervals, we must have a 11*4 storage matrix to save all sorted eigenvectors (corresponded to `orthoevecs` in the bellow code)

```
nx = 2; intervals = 0.2; diprandom = 4; j=0;
storagematrix = ConstantArray[0, {diprandom*(Round[nx/intervals] + 1), diprandom}];

Do[
     testmatrix = (2 - r)*RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {diprandom, diprandom}];

     {evalvs, evecs} = Eigensystem[testmatrix];
     {evalvs, orthoevecs} = {evalvs[[#]], Orthogonalize[evecs[[#]]]} &@ Ordering[evalvs];

   Do[
     storagematrix[[(i + j) ;;]] = orthoevecs[[i]];
   ,{i, 1, 4}];
  j+=4;
,{r, 0, nx, intervals}];
```

But the problem which I face is in bellow picture (which is related to storage matrix as `storagematrix // N // MatrixForm`)

[image]

for r=1.98 and r=2. For r=2, testmatrix is a zero matrix and must have eigenvectors: `{1,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,1}`. But I could not see `{1,0,0,0}`

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What errors do you get?

Comment: I mean I face to this message: Single or list of non-negative machine-sized integers expected at position 2 of ConstantArray[0,{11.`,4}]. >>

Comment: That's a rather informative error, isn't it? `11.` is a `Real`, not an integer. If you make `interval` an exact number, at least that problem should go away.

Comment: You are right but we must multiply by another factor: {diprandom*(Round[nx/intervals] + 1)

Comment: Also we must replace j+=1 with j+=4, but we face to a big problem yet which I write in the main question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the behaviour of `Set`. Consider the following example:

```
a = {1,2,3,4,5};
a[[2;;]] = {1,2,3,4}
a[[3;;]] = {1,2,3,4}
a[[4;;]] = {1,2,3,4}
a[[5;;]] = {1,2,3,4}
```

Notice that in the `[[2;;]]` part, Mathematica decides you want to replace elements 2, 3, 4 and 5 of `a` with the corresponding elements `1, 2, 3, 4` rather than all with the list `{1,2,3,4}`. You can fix this by `storagematrix[[(i + j)]]` instead of `storagematrix[[(i + j) ;;]]`.

In a more Mathematica-idiomatic style, by the way, your program would (I think) be (up to some simple reordering of the eigenvectors which I don't have time to check now):

```
Flatten[Last /@ 
  SortBy[Transpose@
    MapAt[Orthogonalize,
          Eigensystem[(2-#) RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {4, 4}]],
          2],
   First] & /@
   Range[0, 2, 0.2],
1]
```

This is quite a bit faster for larger inputs.

To match your input more exactly:

```
Block[{nx=2, intervals=0.2, diprandom=4},
 Flatten[Last /@ 
  SortBy[Transpose@
    MapAt[Orthogonalize,
          Eigensystem[(nx-#) RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {diprandom, diprandom}]],
          2],
   First] & /@
   Range[0, nx, intervals],
 1]
]
```

Comment: your code is shorter and faster mine. It works very well, Thanks a bunch for that. I named the result (before Flatten...) "stored=". If we write this code  `larglist={};Do[
 Do[
   If[Norm[sorted[[i]].sorted[[i + n]]] < 0.5, 
    AppendTo[largelist, Norm[sorted[[i]].sorted[[i + n]]]]]
   
   , {n, 4, 7}];
 , {i, 1, 36, 4}]`.... in order to multiply each eigenvector of every number in `_Range_` to the each eigenvector of next number in the `_Range_`, and a comparison with `0.5` and save in `larglist` this code works, but how can I shorten this one, because it seems you are professional OP.

Comment: @Ackaran, you have some typos (`largelist` instead of `larglist`, and the `i` bound should probably go up to 37).

`Norm /@ Flatten[
   First[#1].Transpose[#2] & @@@ 
    Partition[Partition[storagematrix, 4], 2, 1]] // Select[# < 0.5 &]`

However, you should probably post this as a new question or an amendment to your current question - I'm not sure what official policy is.

It's worth getting used to the list manipulation functions. (I'm not professional, by the way, but a student.)

Comment: Not only you are professional to Math but also your so intelligent, You are right. 37 and largelist are completely correct.